# How to print out multiple responses not just the first line

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
  if(response){
            const temp = response[0];
            const recipient_id = temp["recipient_id"];
            const recipient_msg = temp["text"];
```

I have this if statement where it only prints out the first response (response[0]), how would I print out multiple responses regardless of what amount not just the first line.

Comment: That's not possible to answer without more context. You say "print", but there is nothing here that would be considered printing. You'll need a loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Array#forEach` or a `for ... of` loop to iterate over the array.

```js
for (const r of response) {
    console.log(r); // or extract individual properties to log
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering that the input is similar to the following:

```
const response = [
    {
        recipient_id: 1,
        text: "t1"
    },
    {
        recipient_id: 2,
        text: "t2"
    }
];
```

you can loop on the `response` array using [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) (as [@Unmitigated](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9513184/unmitigated) mentioned) and print details like `recipient_id` or `text` of each element `r`:

```
if (response) {
    response.forEach((r) => {
        console.log(r.recipient_id, r.text);
    });
}
```

In this example, the output is the following:

```
1 't1'
2 't2'
```